# Alexa skill intent does not use the list of words in my slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Assuming I have an alexa skill with the following intents:

```
{
"intents": [
  {
      "intent": "aaa",
      "slots": []
  },
  {
      "intent": "bbb",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "City",
          "type": "CITIES"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
      "intent": "ccc",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "City",
          "type": "CITIES"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
      "intent": "ddd",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "City",
          "type": "CITIES"
        },
        { "name": "Name",
          "type": "USER_NAMES"}
      ]
  },
 ]
}
```

Assuming I use this simple Utterances:

```
ddd tell me if user {Name} lives in the {City}.
```

By doing so I assumed that in my alexa skill as long as my Intent is calling will provide in Slot Name one of **Names** in my custom slot and in slot City one of the **Cities** in my custom slot.

However, the result is that I am getting free text which I did not provide within the custom slot. the free text if you say the words sounds like what I said, but means different things.

I am not quite sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is as designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and is a common source of confusion: the list of words you provide for the custom slot is taken as a guide, not a definitive set.

Since it is a source of confusion they published a blog post about it:
[Why a Custom Slot is the Literal Solution](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/Why-a-Custom-Slot-is-the-Literal-Solution)

Also, note that there are built-in slot types for cities that you can use and build off of, see here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference

Comment: If that is the case I don't understand how alexa can even work.for example, As I said I have a list of names It  never provides my one of my names, it always provides a free-text that sounds like the name. so how can I do something list that ?

Comment: Well, yes, it does sound odd if it never provides one of the words from your list.  Are your words unconventional - might it not know how those words are supposed to sound?

Comment: They are names first and last names

Comment: I think names could be very tricky due to pronunciation issues.  What if you put in a very straight-forward name like Jane Smith?  Is it able to match that OK?  If it still won't match then something else must be going on.  Could there be a locale issue - do the events you receive show the locale you expect?

Comment: I have now a slot with only the name Amir in it, when I say the name it return : Amil , Meal stuff like that... it is useless..

Comment: I think its ability to distinguish words is not as good as people think (or need).  One of the things I do is use a substitution table to correct the common mistakes it makes.

Comment: What bothering me the most is that all of the alexa skills samples are not validating what comes in. so it gives the impression that you it must be one of the slots items. I also noticed that some times there is no value for a specific slot..